# CarouFredSel: Weird behaviour, current image/slide is not showing after move to the next image/slide on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, caroufredsel

I use CarouFredSel, when I open it in mobile safari (iOS) it shows weird behaviour. When I swipe to move to next slide/image, current image is not showing, I have to tap again to show current image.

Here is the url https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6922502/hellonemo/home.html

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Thanks.